# Apache subdirectory as main server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have a VirtualServer at `api.host.com` and I need to access the same content at `app.host.com/api`.

In Apache a have the following rule in httpd.conf :

```
<VirtualHost app.host.com>
    DocumentRoot "C:\webserver\public\webapp"
    ServerName app.host.com
    <Directory "C:\webserver\public\webapp">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>    
    Alias /api/ "C:/webserver/public/api/"
    <Directory "C:/webserver/public/api/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in `C:/webserver/public/webapp`, .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm getting 404 not found when I access `app.host.com/api/test` but in `app.host.com/api` it is all ok.

In `C:/webserver/public/api`, .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And works just fine with `api.host.com/test`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the order of your rules. Your first rule's `^(.*)$` regex is matching all of your requests, so you need your api stuff before that rule gets a chance to match the request. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf, I changed the path to

```
Alias /**apicall**/ "C:/webserver/public/api/"
<Directory "C:/webserver/public/api/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

And used Jon Lin hint, changing `.htaccess` rule to

```
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$  /apicall/index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```